# Windows 7 back up creating one large backup set--not incremental. Space now full

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup

For the last year I've been doing backups on a regular basis.  But, the only backup set displayed is from 3/12/2011 - 3/10/2012.  That is, there is one large backup set.  After trying to run manually another backup yesterday, I got an error message telling me there's insufficient space.  But, it now lists the partial backup that was run last night (first time for a separate set being listed).

What do I do now?  If I delete the single backup set, I'm going to get rid of a year's worth of backup.  I thought that the software managed the increments and only backed up what was new.

Why don't I see multiple backup sets so that I can delete some previous ones?

Answer (score 1):

> Why don't I see multiple backup sets so that I can delete some
>   previous ones?

My guess because of your original selection.

Get a larget backup media, transfer the file, then resolve the backup problem.